# Does resigning from industry job before probation / 'CV gap' reflect badly in PhD application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, industry

I finished my masters (UK) in media studies last year, and hope to apply for PhD this year. I recently resigned from an industry job at a large MNC during probation.

It is an industry job which I intended to keep while preparing for my PhD application and gaining 'real world' experience (since my topic of interest is related to this industry). However it turned out I could not manage the heavy workload (12-hour days and long commute), researching schools, preparing for GRE and other tests, hence I resigned before I was a confirmed staff so I didn't have to give a longer notice, and hoped to get another job when I feel ready again. I believe I did make solid contributions while on said job; and have had industry placement in the same area during my undergrad years; if these are relevant.

So my questions are,

> Would keeping this job which I quitted during probation on my CV reflect badly in PhD applications? Should I just not list it, and let there be a (almost a year long) gap? If not, how should I mention it?

I have this concern because many current students in top programs (US, UK, Europe) in my field had industry experiences, and I am worried I am not competitive enough.

My field is media and cultural studies.

Comment: Please ask [one question per post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/welcome-to-academia-se/1204#1204). I've edited the secondary questions out of this one. You can ask the other questions (e.g. "what can you do now to fill the gap if you can't find a research assistant job") in separate posts if you like.

Comment: (1) Definitely mention it. Always keep your CV honest and complete. (2) I'm unfamiliar with your field; but in the fields I'm familiar with, a fairly casual "Was excited about opportunity, and to gain some industry experience, but my passion is academia" should be enough. A lot of people don't go straight from undergrad to Ph.D. - most of those worked in industry for a while to realize that they'd rather do research. I don't see how *when* you quit matters. Shouldn't be a biggie. (this is not commenting on whatever field-specific requirements or conventions you allude to)

Comment: @gnometorule Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can vote for it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Definitely mention it. Always keep your CV honest and complete.
2. I'm unfamiliar with your field; but in the fields I'm familiar with, a fairly casual "Was excited about opportunity, and to gain some industry experience, but my passion is academia" should be enough. A lot of people don't go straight from undergrad to Ph.D. - most of those worked in industry for a while to realize that they'd rather do research. I don't see how when you quit matters. Shouldn't be a biggie. (I'm not commenting on whatever field-specific requirements or conventions you allude to)